# How could I solve local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was learning the tensorflow recently and found some project for practicing.

This is a project using CNN to recognized the numbers in verification code.

The traceback as below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19980/362272536.py in <module>
      4         test()
      5     else:
----> 6         train()

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19980/1041537726.py in train()
      7             if x.shape == (10, 20, 80, 1):
      8                 with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
----> 9                     logits = model(x)
     10                     y_onehot = tf.one_hot(y, depth = 10)
     11 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'model' referenced before assignment
```

This is my main function

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    choice_flag = 1
    if os.path.exists(model_dir) and choice_flag == 1:
        test()
    else:
        train()
```

And this is my model

```
model = Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = [3,3], padding = "same", activation = tf.nn.relu),
    layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = [2,2], strides = 2, padding = 'same'),

    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = [3,3], padding = 'same', activation = tf.nn.relu),
    layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = [2,2], strides = 2, padding = 'same'),
    layers.Flatten(),

    layers.Dense(128),
    layers.Dense(40),
    layers.Reshape([4,10])
])
```

Following the trackback, the error located in this block(the train function)

```
def train():
    if os.path.exists(model_dir):
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', compile = False)
    
    for epoch in range(20):
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_db):
            if x.shape == (10, 20, 80, 1):
                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    logits = model(x)
                    y_onehot = tf.one_hot(y, depth = 10)

                    loss_ce = tf.losses.MSE(y_onehot, logits)
                    loss_ce = tf.reduce_mean(loss_ce)

                grads = tape.gradient(loss_ce, model.trainable_variables)
                optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

                if epoch % 10 == 0:
                    print(epoch, step, 'loss:', float(loss_ce))
    
    model.save('model.h5')
```

I have no idea what's going on

All codes as below

```
import os
from random import choice
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, optimizers, Sequential, metrics
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_array_ops import tensor_scatter_add_eager_fallback
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

train_data_dir = 'C:/Users/PeterWu/VScode/Bham/ValCode/train'
test_data_dir = 'C:/Users/PeterWu/VScode/Bham/ValCode/test'
model_dir = 'C:/Users/PeterWu/VScode/Bham/ValCode/model.h5'

def denoising(image):
    threshold = 128
    for i in range(image.width):
        for j in range(image.height):
            r, g, b = image.getpixel((i, j))
            if (r > threshold or g > threshold or b > threshold):
                r = 255
                g = 255
                b = 255
                image.putpixel((i,j), (r,g,b))
            else:
                r = 0
                g = 0
                b = 0
                image.putpixel((i,j), (r,g,b))
    
    image = image.convert('L')
    return image

def gen_train_data(filePath):
    train_file_name_list = os.listdir(filePath)
    x_data = []
    y_data = []

    for selected_train_file_name in train_file_name_list:
        if selected_train_file_name.endswith('.png'):

            captcha_image = Image.open(os.path.join(filePath, selected_train_file_name))

            captcha_image = denoising(captcha_image)
            captcha_image_np = np.array(captcha_image)

            img_np = np.array(captcha_image_np)

            x_data.append(img_np)
            y_data.append(np.array(list(selected_train_file_name.split('.')[0])).astype(np.int))
    
    x_data = np.array(x_data).astype(np.float)
    y_data = np.array(y_data)
    return x_data, y_data


(x,y) = gen_train_data(train_data_dir)
(x_test, y_test) = gen_train_data(test_data_dir)
print(x.shape, y.shape)

def preprocess(x,y):
    x = 2 * tf.cast(x, dtype = tf.float32) / 255.-1
    x = tf.expand_dims(x, -1)
    y = tf.cast(y, dtype = tf.int32)

    return x,y

batch_size = 10
train_db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y))
train_db = train_db.map(preprocess).batch(batch_size)

test_db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test,y_test))
test_db = test_db.map(preprocess).batch(1)

model = Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = [3,3], padding = "same", activation = tf.nn.relu),
    layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = [2,2], strides = 2, padding = 'same'),

    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = [3,3], padding = 'same', activation = tf.nn.relu),
    layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = [2,2], strides = 2, padding = 'same'),
    layers.Flatten(),

    layers.Dense(128),
    layers.Dense(40),
    layers.Reshape([4,10])
])

model.build(input_shape = [None, 20, 80, 1])
model.summary()

optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3)

def train():
    if os.path.exists(model_dir):
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', compile = False)
    
    for epoch in range(20):
        for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_db):
            if x.shape == (10, 20, 80, 1):
                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    logits = model(x)
                    y_onehot = tf.one_hot(y, depth = 10)

                    loss_ce = tf.losses.MSE(y_onehot, logits)
                    loss_ce = tf.reduce_mean(loss_ce)

                grads = tape.gradient(loss_ce, model.trainable_variables)
                optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

                if epoch % 10 == 0:
                    print(epoch, step, 'loss:', float(loss_ce))
    
    model.save('model.h5')

def test():
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', compile=False)
    for step, (x,y) in enumerate(test_db):
        if x.shape == (1, 20, 80, 1):
            logits = model(x)
            logits = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
            pred = tf.cast(tf.argmax(logits, axis = 2), dtype = tf.int32)
            print('Prediction:',pred[0].numpy(),'GroundTruth:',y[0].numpy())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    choice_flag = 1
    if os.path.exists(model_dir) and choice_flag == 1:
        test()
    else:
        train()
```

Comment: `if os.path.exists(model_dir): model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', compile = False)` - it looks like in the `train` function if the model_dir doesnt exists your code still tries to go ahead and use it. `logits = model(x)`

Comment: In `train`: `if os.path.exists(model_dir): ...` What do you want to happen if model_dir doesn't exist? Is that an error? Should you raise an exception there?

Answer (score 3):

In your final if-else block, `train` is called only if `model_dir` does not exist. And inside the `train` function, `model.h5` file is loaded (and `model` variable is created) only if `model_dir` exists. This means that any time train function is called, model variable will not be defined.